# ¿Cómo borro los datos de un formulario una vez enviados en PHP?

Tags: php, formularios

Lo que quiero conseguir es:

Tengo un formulario, en el que el usuario introduce datos en un textarea, le da a enviar y se envía correctamente y te dirije a ellos, pero si el usuario da click el botón `"Atrás"` del navegador, aparece el `textarea` con los datos que introdujo y puede darle a enviar otra vez.

Quiero que al darle "atrás", me borre lo escrito en el `textarea`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto podría lograrlo si  al formulario asigna la propiedad `autocomplete` en `off`  , según la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/form)  nos dice sobre el valor `off` de esta propiedad.

> **off**: El usuario debe ingresar explicitamente cada valor dentro de cada
>   campo por cada uso, o el documento provee su propio método de
>   autocompletado; `el navegador no autocompleta las entradas`.

```
<form autocomplete="off">
```

Con `Jquery`  podría escuchar el evento [pageshow](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/pageshow)  del elemento `window` , cuando se dé dicho evento , aplicamos el `reset` al `form`.

```
$(window).bind("pageshow", function() {
    $("#miform")[0].reset();
});
```

Comment: ¡Me funcionó! Pero algo que añadir es que sí al darle al botón volver, podría estar el textarea listo para escribir y no tener que darle click de nuevo

Comment: Eso no especifico en su pregunta. Pero ya después del reset podría aplicar el `focus` al elemento que desee.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, lo probaré

Answer (score 0):

Eso lo haces por medio de Jquery yo te lo recomiendo quedaría de la siguiente forma.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#id_botonregresar").click(function(){
    $('#id_textarea').html("");
    });
});
```

Necesitas agregar la libreria de Jquery para esto en tu index...

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```